# Difference between finding normal vector to given surface using gradient and $r_u\times r_v$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surface-integrals

When calculating surface integral in scalar field, we use the following formula:
[image: surface integral formula for scalar field]

Now, in the example solved below;[image: example of surface integral]

For surface **S1**, they have calculated $r_(theta) × r_z$ for finding the normal vector, which is clear to me. But my question is whether we can use gradient to find the same normal vector and then its modulus to be replaced in the integral because in my class, our teacher has used gradient for finding the unit normal vector in many examples in surface integrals over vector field given by the formula[image: surface integral over vector field]

Now, if I calculate the gradient of the surface I get **n**= 2x **i**+ 2y **j**  and **|n|** = 2 instead of 1 found out by $r_(theta) × r_z$ in the solved question above. As a result if I substitute 2 in place of |$r_(theta) × r_z$|  the whole integral value gets multiplied by 2 which certainly gives the wrong answer. I am really confused as to why the magnitude of the normal vector differs in the two cases and how to differentiate where to use the gradient and where the cross-product for calculations. Also, if normals can be found using gradient, then why at all we have been introduced with the method of using the cross product which is quite tedious to find in some cases, to find the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the surface $S$ is given as a level set of some function $f$, then its normal is in fact parallel to the gradient of $f$.

But $\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v$ has information about *magnitude* in it which cannot be obtained from $\nabla f$. The fact that $\nabla f$ doesn't have this information is easy to understand: if $S$ is given by $f=c$, then it is also given by $af=ac$ for any real number $a$, and the functions $af$ have different gradients. They point in the same direction (or exactly opposite directions for negative $a$) but they have entirely different magnitudes.

In short, what the gradient can do for you (for surfaces given as level sets) is to find $\mathbf{n}$. This is OK if you can use some geometry to perform an integral $dS$, but that is usually not possible. The gradient cannot tell you how to convert $dS$ into $|J(u,v)| du dv$, however.

Comment: Then, which magnitude does $r_u × r_v$ gives actually?

Comment: @Esha The magnitude of $\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v$ at each $(u_0,v_0)$ is intuitively the ratio between the area of a small region $R$ on the surface near $\mathbf{r}(u_0,v_0)$ and the area of the region in the $(u,v)$ plane that maps into $R$. You can think of it as a generalization of the Jacobian determinant for changes of variable in 2D integrals; the Jacobian determinant is what falls out of evaluating $\| \mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v \|$ when $\mathbf{r}$ parametrizes a flat surface.

Comment: Does that mean the Jacobian is a generalized form of the normal vectors to be used in different scenarios?

Comment: @Esha It is really the other way around. You can think of a change of variable in 2D integrals as a special case of parametrizing a surface integral in the case when the surface you want to parametrize is flat. The Jacobian determinant that you get from the change of variable, with the absolute value, is exactly $\| \mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v \|$. But with this cross product method, we can also deal with curved surfaces in three dimensional space.

Comment: What do you mean by **level set of some function**?

Comment: So, for curved sufaces, normal vectors cannot be found by gradient??

Comment: @ Esha if you used the gradient of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$ to get the normal vector for the surface $S_1$ (which is contained in the level set $f(x,y,z)=1$), could you show me how you would set up your integral $\int\int_{S_1}zdS$?

Comment: You could use the gradient of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$ to get the normal vector of $S_1$, but you still need to integrate *over* $S_1$ which would inevitably require some parameterization of $S_1$.

Comment: @Esha A level set of a function is the set of points where it is equal to some given value. The gradient of a function is normal to its level sets, which is the connection you're looking at. So you can use the gradient to find the unit normal vector $\mathbf{n}$.

Comment: @Esha (Cont.) But the gradient cannot help you deal with the surface area element $dS$. Occasionally, things work out really nicely so that that isn't a problem. For example, if the integrand is constant, then the surface integral is just that constant times the surface area, and maybe we can compute the surface area without doing an integral (like for a sphere or cylinder). But usually we can't.

Comment: @Matthew Holder So after parameterization, we need to calculate the Jacobian to convert dS into dA which may come out to be different from the normal vector actually?

Comment: @lan So basically gradient vector is useful when finding unit normal vector and it has nothing to do with dS in case of scalar fields? In case of scalar fields we need to calculate the Jacobian for converting the surface element dS into dA?

Comment: @Esha Whether you're dealing with a vector dotted with the vector dS or a scalar field, either way you will usually need to convert dS into dA using this cross product method.

Comment: If I were you I would always parameterize surfaces to evaluate surface integrals. Look at how your textbook evaluated $\int\int_{S_3}zdS$. It may appear as if they used gradients to calculate this surface integral, but in reality they enforced the parameterization $\vec{r}(u,v)=(u,v,1+u)$ defined over the unit disc $u^2+v^2 \leq 1$.

Comment: @lan That means Jacobian and normal vectors are different things and give different results when calculated for a particular case, right?

Comment: Yeah textbooks can make this unnecessarily confusing when they separate out the case of $z=f(x,y)$ (as in the third integral in the OP) being parametrized as $(x,y,f(x,y))$ and give this case its own formula. There is no need to remember the resulting formula separately, it is ultimately a special case of the same cross product formula (though it is a little bit easier to derive).

Comment: @Esha I am really not sure what you mean by that. I think my reference to Jacobians confused you, sorry about that. I was just trying to make a connection to something closely related you might be more familiar with.

Comment: @Matthew Yes, exactly. I got confused because it is written in another place that unit normal **n** = ($r_u × r_v$)/|$r_u × r_v$| , that's why I thought that only the normal vector found using gradient will give $r_u × r_v$

Comment: @Esha For a level set, you can find the unit normal either by normalizing $r_u \times r_v$ or by normalizing the gradient. But there is no way to use the gradient to get $\| r_u \times r_v \|$ which, if you look carefully at your formulas for computing surface integrals by parametrization, is always needed. Either you have $r_u \times r_v$ appearing unnormalized in the formula or you have the magnitude explicitly in the formula, either way knowing only the unit normal is not enough.

Comment: @lan No, no I am familiar with Jacobians but the confusion aroused due to the formula of unit normals as I mentioned in the last comment. Can you please clarify that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112191/discussion-between-esha-and-ian).

Comment: You can parameterize the surface $z=f(x,y)$ with the standard parameterization $$\vec{r}(u,v)=(u,v,f(u,v))$$ It turns out that $$dS=||\vec{r}_u\times\vec{r}_v||dA=\sqrt{1+(f_x(u,v))^2+(f_y(u,v))^2}dA$$ But this formula is only valid for the parameterization we just developed. In fact, if we parameterized the surface $z=f(x,y)$ by $$\vec{r}(u,v)=\Big(u^3,v^5,f\big(u^3,v^5\big)\Big)$$  then we would get a totally different surface area component $dS$. In other words, $dS$ is completely determined by how you parameterize the surface, and this may or may not equal the modulus of some gradient.

Comment: @Matthew That completely clarifies my doubt. I am grateful that you and lan helped me a lot to clear my conception.

Answer (score 0):

This formula is for a scalar values function f.

[image]

And this function is for a vector valued function f.

[image]

The example then goes on to discuss a problem with a scalar valued function.  There is no need to need to calculate a normal vector in this case.

Comment: Within the method that they are using, you find a normal vector in order to find the area scale factor $\frac{dS}{dA}=\| \mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v \|$, even when integrating a scalar valued function on the surface. This is the usual way it's done in calculus textbooks.

Comment: $(\mathbf r_u\times \mathbf r_v)$ does generate a normal vector.  And $\|(\mathbf r_u\times \mathbf r_v)\|$ generates the scaling factor.  The $\frac {\mathbf n}{\|\mathbf n\|}$ factor can be distraction in some ways, as $(\mathbf r_u\times \mathbf r_v) = \frac {\mathbf n}{\|\mathbf n\|}\|(\mathbf r_u\times \mathbf r_v)\|$

Comment: Yeah, this has been a point of confusion when I have taught this subject before: technically, you can do a flux integral by finding the unit normal $\mathbf{n}$, dotting the vector field with it, and integrating the resulting scalar field $dS$...but if you're doing the calculation by parametrizing the surface, you wind up dividing by $\| \mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_v \|$ to normalize the normal vector and then multiplying by it again to incorporate $dS/dA$.

Comment: (Cont.) That's all technically correct, and provides a theoretical connection between the two, but it's easier to do *calculations* by thinking of them as distinct. Anyway, the point of my previous comment was that even when doing a surface integral of a scalar field, if you're using parametrization, you still typically construct a normal vector anyway, even though its direction is irrelevant.